# VS2013 Build "Does not support previewing"

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Every time I  try to build my solution in VS2013, nothing builds, no errors - But in the status bar it says: "This item does not support previewing"

I googled around a bit but have come up empty.

But if I right click on each project and select build it works fine.

Any ideas?

Perhaps this message is totally unrelated... [Post hoc ergo propter hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc)

Steps to reproduce on my machine:

1. Right Click any project in solution:  select build
2. Status bar displays Build successful
3. Right click solution select build
4. Status bar displays : "This item does not support previewing"

Perhaps it isnt related, but it sure does appear to be.

Comment: It is an entirely normal message, projects indeed do not support previewing.  Clearly this has nothing whatsoever to do with the real issue, whatever that might be.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated my question.. You may be right but I can perform the listed steps and get that result reliably.

Comment: You are mesmerized by this message like a moth to a 10 kilovolt bug zapper.  If the build doesn't build anything then first use Build + Clean to get rid of the obvious reason, next use Build + Configuration Manager and verify that the Build checkboxes are ticked.

Comment: Same issue here. It is definitely not related to the error message you're getting - just a coincidence... Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: What worked for me now was to disable 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this... Somehow nothing was selected to build in the solution configuration. I right clicked on the solution, went to properties and then selected COnfiguration Properties and clicked the Build box for all the projects...

I have no idea how they became unchecked, only thing I can think of is a co-worker was trolling me.....

Comment: Happened today in VS2019 also. Changed build config from Debug => Release => Debug and the problem went away

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem (i.e. debug not starting, and no error message) with Visual Studio 2015 in the following two cases:

1. after loading a solution that had previously been built with Visual Studio 2010
2. and also after using the "save as" function in Visual Studio 2015 to update a solution that had been started with Visual Studio 2010 (using Save as updates the solution file and sets the active Visual Studio version to 14 - i.e. VS 2015).

In both cases, deleting the bin and obj directories under the startup project fixed the problem. It's also worth closing visual studio and making sure that there are no {yourprojectname}.vshost.exe processes still running - if there are then kill them before running visual studio again. On that note, if you have multiple versions of visual studio on your machine, you should also check that you don't have the same solution open in the other version of visual studio at the same time (I've done that one myself).

One of the comments here suggests disabling the "enable visual studio hosted process" option. Don't do that if you can at all avoid it: you'll lose lots of debugging functionality (particularly in the area of being able to edit code while your solution is running).

Hope that helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for VS2015
"this item does not support previewing" vs2015 (Visual Studio 2015/2016)

Step 1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features

Step 2. Uninstall all: Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.10586.15 (maybe you have diff ver)

Step 3. Download new latest Windows Software Development Kit
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=619296

Install & Create new project, Done!

Dclick on MainPage.xaml and you will see Loading designer...

Comment: my OS Windows 10, 64bit, Enterprise, running on vmware player with KSAuto crack, disabled windows update and windows defender.

Answer (score 0):

```
1: Add below lines in App.conf
<specFlow>
<unitTestProvider name="MSTest"></unitTestProvider>
</specFlow>

2: add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTestTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
right click on your project and select: Add Reference

3: add using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; in Step Defination

4: goto feature file and run it. This is what solve my problem on vs2013
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with .aspx file. I just right click on the .aspx file and select open with (HTML Editor). You can choose any form the list.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue for me, I have opened a project in VS 2010 and then when I open the same in VS 2015 then his error has occurred.

Solution:
By Closing the VS2010 project solution fixed the issue.